# Solve $n!\gt\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality, functional-inequalities

Let $f(n)=n!$ and $g(n)=\binom{2n}{n}$. Obviously $f(7)\gt g(7)$ and $f(6)\lt g(6)$. The functions are increasing on $n\in (1,\infty)$, $n$ being an integer. But this is not enough to prove
$$n!\gt\binom{2n}{n}\iff n\ge 7.$$

Maybe convexity could help. We could use the fact that $n!$ is convex but I don't know how to prove the convexity of $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$ from this.

Comment: Compute $\frac {f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ and $\frac {g(n+1)}{g(n)}$ to show the left side grows faster than the right

Comment: @Ross Millikan But why is that ratio enough? $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}\gt \frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}$ for $n=3$ but $f(n)\lt g(n)$ for $n=3$. Even if it is interpolated with gamma function, the slope of $f(n)$ at $n=3$ is smaller than the slope of $g(n)$ at $n=3$.

Comment: You have already shown that the left side is greater at $n=7$.  Now what you have shown is enough to show that $g(n)$ never catches up.  You don't care what happens below $n=7$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $$
\frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!^2 }} < \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }},\quad n! > \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} 
$$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then it is enough to show
$$
1 < \left( {\frac{n}{{4e}}} \right)^n \pi \sqrt 2 n
$$
for $n\geq 7$, which is true. (Trivially true for $4e <11 \leq n$ and the cases $n=7,8,9,10$ can be checked by hand.)

You can also argue that
$$
\binom{2n}{n} \le 4^n  < n!.
$$
for $n\geq 9$.

Comment: I like the approach of sandwiching $4^n$ between the bounds, and was going to write it up before I saw this answer.  For completeness: $4^9< 9!$ by direct computation, and that implies $4^n < n!$ for larger $n$ by induction.